# Setting the y value for a ROC

Tags: r, roc

Apologies for a very basic question. I'm struggling to get R to recognise the y values for a ROC

I'm trying to do a basic ROC but can't seem to set the vector for y.

```
fullmodel= glm(culture_positive ~  No_symptoms + sex + art_status_v1 +current_cd4 + 
               bmi_v1 +nurse_tb_diagnosis_crp_v1 + temperature_v1,
               family="binomial",  data= Data1)
roc(y , fullmodel$fitted.values, plot=TRUE)
```

> Error in roc(y, fullmodel$fitted.values, plot = TRUE) : 
>     object 'y' not found

So 'y' is a column in my dataset Data1 labelled 'culture_positive' as per the glm but whatever I try I keep getting this message that 'y' is not found.

Once again, apologies for a basic question but it is really holding me up.

Comment: Hi, what package is the `roc` function you use from? Please include all `library` and `require` calls or the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question.

Comment: Sorry- library is pROC

Answer (score 1):

Since `y` is not in your global environment you need to specify where to find `y`. You can either use the value you used to fit the model:

```
roc(culture_positive , fullmodel$fitted.values, plot=TRUE)
```

or the response stored in the `glm` object

```
roc(fullmodel$y , fullmodel$fitted.values, plot=TRUE)
```

I would recommend the second option, it's somewhat safer, because you take `y` and `fitted.values` from the same object, so they will fit together.